# Displaying images on one line with BS3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello I'm new to bootstrap and I want to display these images on one line. Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      <img src="img/LOGO2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <img src="img/w.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <img src="img/f.jpg">
        <img src="img/y.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try setting float left on both images.

Comment: Only the image in the center goes back and the two images for facebook and youtube stay on the down line.

Comment: I think i didn't understand it right. If you want all four images on one line add this to your css file. '.row div div{float:left;}'

Comment: They do display on one line: http://bootply.com/109175

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your viewing the document on a small window, such as a mobile device then the images will drop down and not appear on the same line.

Add another prefix class to your div element for extra small devices `.col-xs`

- `.col-xs-*` Extra small devices (<768px)
- `.col-sm-*` Small devices Tablets (≥768px)
- `.col-md-*` Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)
- `.col-lg-*` Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/e9yN5/